# How to display the radius in MKCircle on Map in meters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I need to draw a circle of a radius 1.23 metre on MkMapView using MKCircle.
How would i show that on the map.
I used the following ,

```
  r = 1.23;// in metres.
  circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:r];
```

But when i draw it on the map it looks like more than 1km on the MKMapView.
Could someone please tell me how i could represent a circle of radius 1.23 metre on the map??

This is mainly to show the accuracy of the location, so the radius indicates the accuracy of the location.

Comment: 1 metre, 1km, 1 m?  Do you mean km in all cases?

Comment: i mean 1 metre , but when i display the radius = 1.23 metre, the circle on the map displays as if it is more than 1.23 km

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewForOverlay` delegate method, try setting the `lineWidth` of the `MKCircleView` to 1.

I think the default width of 0 results in the "road width".

Answer (score 0):

MKCircle class definition says

> *radius*
>
> ```
>    The radius of the circle, measured in meters from the center point.
> ```

So your code should work fine.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html